# Designing an example `return` and `>>=` for int option addition

Tags: ocaml, option-type, monads

Just to exercise the concepts of a monad, I am trying to write an OCaml program with a `return` and `>>=` function, which makes sense for the `int option` type.  In particular, it seems to me that however these are defined, it should permit one to write

`let x = (return 1) >>= (return 2) >>= oplus;;`

and `x` should store `Some 3`.  I take the definition of `return` to be obvious.  I believe the sensible definition for `>>=` should be

```
let (>>=) (wrapped : int option) (handler : int -> 'a option) : 'a option = 
  match wrapped with 
  | None -> None 
  | Some i -> handler i
```

But I'm not quite clear about how `oplus` should be defined, since I think we should have `(return 2) >>= oplus` evaluate to the function

```
fun i -> Some(i+2)
```

But as such the result of the bind on these arguments is ill-typed.

So clearly I'm misunderstanding something -- I'm guessing somehow I'm wrong about thinking that `Some 11 >>= Some 2 >>= oplus` should evaluate to `Some 13`.  But I thought that was kind of the idea or the point of bind, is to act like a data pipline feeding data into functions that unwrap it, compute, and then wrap it again at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `return` is implemented as:

```
let return (x: int) = Some x
```

Then `(return 1) >>= (return 2)` is equivalent to writing `Some 1 >>= Some 2`.

This doesn't work, because `>>=` expects the right hand side to be a function.

```
utop # (return 1) >>= (return 2);;
Error: This expression has type int option
       but an expression was expected of type int -> 'a option
```

If we try the following, it fails because of the associativity of the `>>=` operator.

```
return 11 >>= return 2 >>= oplus
```

This is being parsed as:

```
(return 11 >>= return 2) >>= oplus
```

If we disambiguate that order with:

```
return 11 >>= (return 2 >>= oplus)
```

Then the right-hand operand is an `int option` and again, the types do not work out.